# Internet stops for only one computer over wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

Several times a day, I will be minding my own business when my internet drops out. It only affects my computer, as two other PC's are in the same room and have issues. I also experience slower internet speeds than the others. This is all on WiFi. I can fix the issue by rebooting.

Specs: Intel i5 6600 @ 3.3 GHz, GeForce 1060 3 GB, 16 GB DDR4 RAM

I will provide more information at request.

Comment: What is your network adapter model?

Answer (score 0):

On the problem computer, update the wireless driver, restart, go into Windows Power Management settings, and set the Wireless card to High Performance. The default setting allows the wireless card to turn off.  When done setting changes, do a final restart and test